# Limit service principal to only manage membership for a single security group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to manage group membership for a single group in an automated way. My AD administrator has created an app & service principal, but is hesitant to give it `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` permission. This permission seems to give ability to manage membership for **all** groups.

Is there a way to limit permissions or scope to manage membership to a single AD security group?

Answer (score 0):

I think currently this is not possible because, Most of the Graph permissions are tenant-wide, without a way to restrict them in scope.

such as the app access policies we have in Exchange Online: [Application access policies](https://practical365.com/application-access-policies-in-exchange-online/)

Hope this is Helpful.